# Web API to query SQL Server and return result is not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from the Web API and return a result set as JSON. But my code shown here is not working as expected. I am trying to return the entire query response as a JSON:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM)
{
    string commandText = "SELECT * from [TDB].[dbo].[results_vw] where ROOM = @ROOM_Data";

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TDBConnection"].ConnectionString;

    var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@ROOM_Data", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@ROOM_Data"].Value = ROOM;

        connection.Open();

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            jsonResult.Append("[]");
        }
        else
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(jsonResult.ToString());

        connection.Close();

        return response;
    }
}
```

This code returns this result:

```
333838362692368203368203368203362692368203359544362692368203362692368203362692368203368203
```

Where I am expecting the JSON as

```
 {"data":
  [
  {"R_ID":"368203","ROOM":"K2"}, 
  {"R_ID":"368203","ROOM":"K2"}
  ]}
```

Now I created a model class called `DatabaseResult` to store the response but I am not sure how I can store the result in to the model class in the controller

```
public class DatabaseResult
{
      public int r_id { get; set; }
      public string room { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is because you are only return the the value from the first column of each row

Comment: I would suggest using the [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) library to help with your ADO calls.

Comment: @Nkosi can I just store the response using the Model class instead of using the extra library?

Comment: Yes. I was just suggesting it as it would make things easier.

Comment: @Nksoi I am not sure how to store them in the Model Class though

Comment: Drafting up an answer now

Comment: What are the names of the columns where those values are to be accessed

Comment: All Columns from the Query response needs be in the JSON. I have 15 columns and I am just showing two here

Comment: Oh. that is where the library would have made things easier. I'll show for the current ones and the same can be applied for the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current result is because you are only return the the value from the first column of each row and adding it to the string builder.

Create a new instance of the model and populate it using the values from the reader for each row.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Getdetails(string ROOM) {
    string commandText = "SELECT * from [TDB].[dbo].[results_vw] where ROOM = @ROOM_Data";
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection)) {
            command.Parameters.Add("@ROOM_Data", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@ROOM_Data"].Value = ROOM;
            connection.Open();
            List<DatabaseResult> records = new List<DatabaseResult>();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    var row = new DatabaseResult {
                        r_id = (int)reader["r_id"],
                        room = (string)reader["room"],
                        //...other properties.
                    };
                    records.Add(row);
                }
                return Ok(records);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above uses the column names as the indexer to get the values from the reader.

Comment: @Nksoi Thanks a ton. I am getting an error at room `room = (string)reader["room"],` saying it doesnot exists in context

Comment: @trx I made an assumption about column name. what is the column that `K2` data could come from? The column names need to those from the table

Comment: It was my mistake I had a semicolon next to `r_id = (int)reader["r_id"],` Now I have the issue with `return Ok(records)` as it says it doesnot exists with the correct context. Is it because I am using `HttpResponseMessage ` as return type

Comment: @trx Yes. Look at the code in my answer and you will see the return type for the action. It simplifies what you had. under the hood it basically does the same thing. This way has a simpler syntax

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just checking can we dump the response from the query in to model class with iterarting through each column names something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatabaseResult>(queryResponse)`? because I get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: @trx Ok in those case you should check the reader first to make sure it is not db null before casting. you could easily create an extension methods to do it.